# How Checking the internet connection in python

Tags: python

```
  import requests 
        def post(self):
                response = requests.get('http://python.org')
                print response.status_code
```

I am trying to find the internet connection but response throwing name error

Answer (score 1):

A simple function w/ requests library.

```
def connection_check():
    try:
        requests.get("http://google.com", timeout=3)
        return True
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        pass

    return False
```

you can adjust URL and timeout according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import requests 
    def post(self):
            response = requests.get('https://www.google.co.in')
            print response.status_code
```

It's throwing NameError as it's not able to obtain IP address for python.org through dns lookup.

Try this on windows command prompt.

Type `nslookup python.org`.

You will find that DNS Lookup operation may be failing. You can also check hosts file present in windows directory.

Comment: It's always nice to add an explanation. Because, your's code and OP's code almost the same.